# Cassandra upgradeSSTable - Does it reads and writes entire data?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

We had an 18 node C* cluster (roughly 600 GB data per node) running 2.0.17. We have expanded it by adding 18 more nodes and hence we need to do a nodetool cleanup to get rid of any redundant data that is no longer owned by old nodes (i.e. the data the has moved from old node to new nodes in the cluster). However, later we also need to upgrade the C* version to 2.1.13 and since this is major point release upgrade we need to run upgradesstables on the tables to make it compatible with 2.1 format. 
So I was wondering how upgradesstables works. Is it going to read entire data and then re-write it in new format or is it something less expansive. If its going to rewrite the whole thing then is it possible that it will also get rid of any foreign data that this node no longer owns? If this is the case then we don't have to run nodetool cleanup first and can upgrade to 2.1.13 and run upgradesstables that will do everything for us. Else we will have to run nodetool cleanup before upgrading to 2.1.13. Due to large amount of data on each node I don't want to go through the entire dataset twice if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It will read and rewrite the entire sstable (only if it needs to). Basically its a single sstable compaction. Writing new sstable as reading it, and once its complete delete the original.

Comment: My main question is, will that mean it will get rid of any foreign data as well that it no longer owns?

Comment: You need to do a cleanup, the normal compactions (which an upgrade table is basically) will not remove things it does not own so you will need both. You cannot just do a cleanup either because the cleanup op will skip sstables that do not contain data outside the nodes ranges.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification!